# Sci-Fi weapon: Satellite shooting laser beams down to earth?

Tags: laser, microwaves, infrared-radiation

[image]

The range of one of [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Denial_System) is stated to be 700m. Since it sends out electromagnetic waves the only problem I see with limited range is the beam divergence. Atmospheric absorption is minimal so slapping this weapon onto a Satellite and firing onto earth below is only a matter of being accurate. If the beam had a diameter of 10metres you could achieve the painthreshold of 1W/cm2 with only 1000kW of power.

> Second- and third-degree burns (complete dermal necrosis) occurs at 45qC after 2 hours, at 48C after 15 minutes and at 60C after 5 seconds.
>
> Laboratory research with animals and human subjects that was published scientifically has investigated various basic issues. For short-term exposure (3s), the pain threshold for a small exposed area (around 1 cm2) is at 1.25 W/cm2 intensity. The threshold seems to be lower by only 20%, namely at 1.0 W/cm2, if an area slightly above 30 cm2 is exposed.

There is a lethal version of this weapon. Here is a physical analysis by Jürgen Altmann taken from [here](https://omeganews.lima-city.de/berichtaltmann2.pdf)

> The Advanced Tactical Laser (ATL), to be carried by a transport
> aircraft, is to emit an infrared laser beam of 300 kilowatts power,
> provided from a chemical reaction. Via a 0.5 m wide transmitting and
> directing mirror, the beam can be focused – under ideal conditions –
> to a spot of 0.1-0.2 m size over 10 km and more. With the 100-fold
> power of a stove plate applied over a similar area, wood or textiles
> would start burning and metal would melt through after fractions of a
> second, under usual atmospheric conditions on the order of one second.
> Strong turbulence will limit the range, fog, dust or heavy rain can
> reduce it markedly. With fuel for about 40 seconds of radiating on
> board and dwell times below a second, the beam will often be directed
> and fired automatically.
>
> The ATL can destroy equipment and kill
> people, it is not a non-lethal weapon. Its usage in armed conflict
> against combatants could be compared with flamethrowers which are
> accepted under international humanitarian law. Compared to other means
> of applying force at many kilometres distance (artillery, bombs), the
> ATL would allow much more discriminating destruction. The ATL has
> limitations: the fuel is sufficient only for around 100 “shots”. A
> clear line of sight is also needed, preventing action through fog or
> heavy rain and exposing the carrier aircraft.

So the question, broadly put, is what is ***physically*** stopping the military from (secretly) slapping one of these onto a Solar powered Satellite that can indefinitely fire laser beams down to earth and take out armies or individuals?

Comment: Please edit your question to say who is the artist who made the picture.

Comment: Physically (or at least terminologically), the denial systens are not laser beams. They are at best maser beams, but I doubt they are very coherent. Irrelevant for the question, but it grates when the title is inherently problematic.

Comment: @AndersSandberg Laser beams was a reference to "Sci-fi weapons" now made possible.

Comment: @BenCrowell No idea who made the picture. What is the issue? Copyright?

Comment: I don't see a physics question here.  At best it's engineering and it could even be about law or politics, as those are also reasons why you don't "slap" weapons on satellites.

Comment: @StephenG The question is what is physically stopping them. It's not about law and politics. I don't think 9/11 was about law and politics or was it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beam divergence is proportional to wavelength $\lambda$ (3.2 mm for the ADS) and inversely proportional to aperture size: $\theta \approx \lambda / \pi D$ if we approximate it as a Gaussian beam. A low LEO satellite $h=200$ km up would disperse its energy over an area $A\approx \pi (\theta h)^2 =  \lambda^2 h^2/\pi D^2$. So if there is a necessary threshold intensity $I_t=10^4$ W/m$^2$ this means $I_0/A>I_t$, or $I_0 > \lambda^2 h^2 I_t / \pi D^2$.

If we plug in the values we get $I_0 > 1.3038\cdot 10^9 / D^2$. For a typical satellite size $D<10$ m, so you need $I_0 = 1.3\cdot 10^7$ W. The ISS has an acre of solar panels giving it about 90 kilowatts, about 144 times less than needed here. So, yes, you could build your pain satellite if you built something about 12 times larger than the ISS. (The larger design would also allow a bit better $D$)

What is stopping military devices like this is cost of launch and maintenance. Not physics.

Comment: Correction: 90 kilowatts are perfectly enough to power the device. It would need 10 million watts to fire beams continuously. So for each beam duration of 5 seconds it's batteries would need to recharge for 12 minutes. Obviously continuous fire is not needed.
The ISS costs 150 billion dollars which is a quarter of what the US spends on defense each year. The "laser cannon" is peanuts compared to that price and obviously the ISS would cost a fraction of its price if firing laser beams down to earth was its only purpose.
So no, its ability to win wars would far outweigh the cost involved.

Comment: @AzulShiva - Issues of military usefulness and fundability are pretty far outside this forum. I would just mention that anti-LEO satellite weaponry exists.

Comment: the point is that it's physically possible. That's all I wanted to know. And if they're not building it, it's because they've got something better.